# Saving Excel File in SharePoint giving error: unauthorized

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am breaking an Excel file into multiple Excel files and uploading them in SharePoint.

While saving the Excel file a pop-up window appears where I have to put the credentials. After putting them in, it throws an unauthorized error.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim uniqueValues As Collection
Dim value As Variant
Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
Dim savePath As String
Dim headerToFilter As String
Dim headersToUnlock As Variant
Dim headerIndexFilter As Long
Dim headerIndexUnlock As Variant
Dim headerRange As Range
Dim fileName As String
Dim SPUrl As String
Dim SPFolder As String
Dim SPUsername As String
Dim SPPassword As String
Dim HTTPReq As Object

' Set SharePoint credentials and URLs
SPUrl = "https://mycompanysharepoint/:f:/s/TreasuryTransformation/"
SPFolder = "Shared%20Documents/General/PO%20Accrual/Excel%20to%20split" ' Path to the SharePoint document library folder
SPUsername = "myemailid@compamanydomain"
SPPassword = "password"
 
' Set the worksheet you want to process
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OpenPO") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name
Set splitws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Split excel")

' Set the table name you want to process
On Error Resume Next
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("OpenPO") ' Replace "TableName" with your table name
On Error GoTo 0
If tbl Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Table 'OpenPO' not found!"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Set the header name you want to filter on
headerToFilter = "Owner" ' Replace "HeaderToFilter" with your header name for filtering
 
' Find the column index of the header to filter
On Error Resume Next
headerIndexFilter = tbl.ListColumns(headerToFilter).Index
On Error GoTo 0
If headerIndexFilter = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Header '" & headerToFilter & "' not found in the table!"
    Exit Sub
End If
 
' Check if there is data in the table
If tbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No data found in the table!"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Check if the filter column contains any Excel Error'
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In tbl.ListColumns(headerIndexFilter).DataBodyRange
    If IsError(cell.value) Then
        MsgBox "Column '" & headerToFilter & "' contains Excel errors. Please Fix them and try again."
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tbl.ListColumns(headerIndexFilter).DataBodyRange, 0) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Column '" & headerToFilter & "' has 0 in place of owner name. Please Fix them and try again."
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
 
' Set the header names for columns to unlock
headersToUnlock = Array("Comment - Reporting Team", "Correction Journal Name") ' Replace with your header names to unlock
 
' Find the column indexes for headers to unlock
ReDim headerIndexUnlock(LBound(headersToUnlock) To UBound(headersToUnlock))
For i = LBound(headersToUnlock) To UBound(headersToUnlock)
    Set headerRange = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Find(headersToUnlock(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not headerRange Is Nothing Then
        headerIndexUnlock(i) = headerRange.Column
         MsgBox "Header '" & headersToUnlock(i) & "' found! at '" & headerRange.Column & "'"
    Else
        MsgBox "Header '" & headersToUnlock(i) & "' not found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i
 
' Get the last row of data in the table
lastRow = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
 
' Create a collection to store unique values from the specified column
Set uniqueValues = New Collection
 
' Loop through the data and collect unique values
On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, headerIndexFilter).value <> "" Then
        uniqueValues.Add tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, headerIndexFilter).value, CStr(tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, headerIndexFilter).value)
    End If
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
 
' Loop through unique values and create separate workbooks
For Each value In uniqueValues
    If value <> "" Then
        ' Filter data based on unique values
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=headerIndexFilter, Criteria1:=value
 
        ' Copy visible cells to a new workbook
        Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        tbl.HeaderRowRange.Copy Destination:=newWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        newWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' Copy filtered data starting from row 2
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear clipboard
        
        ' Apply formatting
        With newWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
            .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Font.Bold = True
        End With
        
        ' Unfilter the original data
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=headerIndexFilter
        
        ' Lock all cells by default
            newWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Locked = True

            ' Unlock specific columns
            For Each headerIndexUnlockValue In headerIndexUnlock
                newWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(headerIndexUnlockValue).Locked = False
            Next headerIndexUnlockValue

            ' Protect the sheet
            newWorkbook.Sheets(1).Protect Password:="test", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

            ' Generate dynamic file name with date and time
            fileName = "Split_" & value & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss") & ".xlsx"

            ' Set the save path and filename
            savePath = Environ("TEMP") & "\" & fileName ' Temporary path with dynamic file name

            ' Save the new workbook temporarily
            newWorkbook.SaveAs savePath
            newWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            
           
            ' Upload file to SharePoint
            Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            HTTPReq.Open "PUT", SPUrl & "/_api/web/GetFolderByServiceRelativeUrl('" & SPFolder & "')/Files/Add(url='" & fileName & "', overwrite=true)", False
            HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f"
            HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(SPUsername & ":" & SPPassword)

            ' Open the file to be uploaded
            Dim fileStream As Object
            Set fileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            fileStream.Open
            fileStream.Type = 1 ' Binary
            fileStream.LoadFromFile savePath

            ' Send the request to upload the file
            HTTPReq.Send fileStream.Read

            ' Check if the upload was successful
            If HTTPReq.Status = 200 Then
                MsgBox "File uploaded successfully to SharePoint."
            Else
                MsgBox "Error uploading file to SharePoint: " & HTTPReq.statusText
                Exit Sub
            End If

            ' Clean up
            fileStream.Close
            Set fileStream = Nothing
            Set HTTPReq = Nothing

            ' Delete the temporary file
            Kill savePath
    End If
Next value

MsgBox "Split and upload operation completed successfully!"
End Sub

    Private Function Base64Encode(ByVal sText As String) As String
Dim arrData() As Byte
arrData = StrConv(sText, vbFromUnicode)
Dim objXML As Object
Dim objNode As Object
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
Base64Encode = objNode.Text
Set objNode = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

The code does multiple operations before storing in SharePoint.

This popup window while saving the Excel file
[image]

Comment: Instead of performing a PUT, if you're logged in then you should be able to call SaveAs with the sharepoint URL as the path.  Have you tried that?   Or sync the folder to your local PC and save the files into the local sync copy.

Comment: @TimWilliams Both options are not possible as this is going to be a client workspace and we have only access through the net. And I checked with the SharePoint Admin also and confirmed that they are not using MFA for SharePoint.